# React fetch changing request url and breaking request / never reaching server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to use fetch like this to inject Authorization headers into my get request:

```
        const req = fetch({
            headers: req_headers,
            method: "GET",
            url: req_url,                
        })
```

When I do it like this, I get an actual response from the server (Unauthorized)

```
        const req = fetch(req_url)
```

But when I do it the first way, inspecting the response value, I see this:

```
        {
             //...
             url: "http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]"
        }
```

When it should say:

```
        {
             //...
             url: req_url
        }
```

And I get the generic react error response message/page:

```
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
```

This is being served from my development server and not the url I am requesting, it also comes instantly.

Why is React/fetch not even trying to contact my server when I send this request and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in `req_url`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the fetch request like this:

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('example', 'some_value');

const requestInfo = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  };

const req = fetch(req_url, requestInfo);
```

Look at [this documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) about fetch. There has a whole section about Header than could help you.

Answer (score 0):

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) as you can read in the documentation can take 2 parameters the url and the configurationObj.

[Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

```js
const fetchResponsePromise = fetch(resource [, init])
```

So your code should be something like this:

```js
const reqConfiguration = {
 headers: req_headers,
 method: "GET",
 body: JSON.stringify({somethingHere})
}

//here is passing the second argument
const req = fetch(req_url, reqConfiguration)
```

I hope this give can help you to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild(run build) the react project after making changes, or else, those changes won't be reflected when you rerun your server; hence, why you're still seeing "http://localhost:3000"... instead of "req_url".
Cheers.